# use method of library imported in another module

Tags: python, python-3.x

In `first.py`, I imported the `datetime` library and called a method which is written in `second.py`. The method works well without importing the `datetime` libirary in `second.py`.

**first.py**

```
from datetime import datetime
import second

def method1(time):
    return datetime.strptime(time,"%Y/%m/%d")

a = method1("2019/08/01")
b = second.method2(a)
```

**second.py**

```
def method2(para1):
    return para1.second
```

**Output**

```
0
```

Should `second.py` import `datetime` so that `para1.second` can work? Can someone help explain the rationale behind?

Comment: Note that you are actually running the code from within `first.py`. the method being executed from there and there the library is known. When you import you get the namespace and so both `method2` and `datetime` are defined in `first.py`. Also note that in `second.py` there is no need to be "aware" of datetime as it is not explicitly used, so no error there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to import modules explicitly when you need to use their names. In `first.py`, for example, you're using things in the `datetime` module directly, and referring to it by name. So, you do `import datetime`, and then call `datetime.strptime()` on that module you imported.

In `second.py`, however, you don't have to do `import datetime`. This is because of how python handles attributes - when you do `para1.second`, python doesn't need to know exactly what type of variable `para1` is - it just checks to see whether it has a field called `second`. And it does, so it returns that. Nowhere in `second.py` are you referring to `datetime` directly - only *indirectly*, via a variable that was defined from it.

Also consider that the `datetime` module does a lot of stuff on its own, and almost certainly imports other dependencies that you're not aware of and you're not importing yourself. But you can still use the `datetime` module, because you don't need to explicitly refer to those modules it's using behind the scenes. They're still in memory somewhere, and if you call certain methods from `datetime`, that code will still get executed, but you don't need to be directly aware of it.

Answer (score 1):

Python usually uses duck typing<sup>1</sup>. This means that instead of requiring a particular type for an object, it looks at the actual attributes it has.

What this means in your case is that `method2` does not care in the slightest whether you pass in a `datetime` object or not. All that's required is that the input `para1` have a `second` attribute.

Importing `datetime` into `second.py` would be counter-productive. It wouldn't affect the operation of your method in any way, but it would polute your namespace and set up an implication that isn't necessarily true.

---

<sup>1</sup> A notable counterexample is a sum of strings, e.g. `sum(['a', 'b'], '')`. Aside from that, your own code can choose what to do as you see fit if course.

Comment: thanks! that's clear. i know it's rather simplified example but just wondering is it normal to construct the code in that way?

Comment: @Nathan. I was hoping to convey that it absolutely is normal. You only import the names that you need. A module is just an object with some attributes on it, just like any other object. You shouldn't import it if you don't need it.